# How to highlight location on an OpenLayers view

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view of locations displayed with OpenLayers. The map, with plot points, is displayed in a left column, and rows of the locations are displayed in a right column.  When a user clicks on one of the locations, I want that row to highlight, and to highlight the plot point to the left.  I also want to record that location ID in the user object as a location preference.

Can I simply do this with AJAX?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example to look at?

Comment: I don't have one since I haven't created it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenLayers Heatmaps](https://drupal.org/project/openlayers_heatmaps) module allows you to create Heatmaps layers through the Openlayers module and it don't have the views integration, but you can highlight the specified location like the below one and honestly I'm not using this before.

[image]

Features

> - Provides a new kind of behavior in the OpenLayers's maps settings.
> - customize the radius, intensity and opacity of each Heatmaps.